# Checkbox From Json is not showing alert when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkbox

I am passing some check box input from `JSON` into `HTML`, and when that checkbox was clicked showing some alert and that not working.
This is my code

```
 $aroundCheck='<div id="content">';foreach ($checkLocation as $checkLocation) {
   $aroundCheck.='<input type="checkbox" name="check[]"/>'.$checkLocation->id_object;
 }
 $aroundCheck.='</div>';
 $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $aroundCheck);
 echo json_encode($result);
```

the javascript

```
$('input=[name="check[]"]').click(function(){ alert("Something");});
```

anybody know? help me im stuck for 2 days

Comment: It seems you are looking for "event delegation".

Comment: Try for `$(document).on('click', 'input=[name="check[]"]', function(){ alert("Something");});`. If this solves your problem, take a look to event delegation as suggested by @Vohuman

Comment: its not work mate, i just want that checkbox its showing some alert on click

Comment: Im find and answer the conclusion like this $("#content").on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
   //this is now the checkbox; this.value is the id.
   alert($(this).val());
});

Comment: I think your selector is wrong.  Should be $('input[name="check[]"]').  Remove the extra equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try with class:

```
$aroundCheck='<div id="content">';foreach ($checkLocation as $checkLocation) {
   $aroundCheck.='<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="checkboxclass"/>'.$checkLocation->id_object;
}
$aroundCheck.='</div>';
$result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $aroundCheck);
echo json_encode($result);
```

javascript

```
$('.checkboxclass').click(function(){ alert("Something");});
```

in most of the cases calling by class will work than calling by name.
and make sure the two functions are not sub functions of two different functions.

if you call a function which is a sub function of `window.onload function` from out side of `window.onload function`.it will not work.